# Code doesn't highlight after loading new edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, edits, live-refresh

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375626/implicit-conversion-lookup-on-template-fails-for-out-of-line-defined-friend-func#10375626) while it got edited, so the "an edit has been made to this post; click to load" button popped up.

[image]

After I clicked it, it reloaded the question but the syntax highlighting was gone.

[image]

Not a big issue, reloading the page helped but it might be annoying. I'm using Safari 5.1.5 on Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 18, same OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch - it will be fixed in the next build.